Mock a Pinia store action used by another store with Jest
I am having difficulty testing nested pinia store actions with jest.
I have the following jest test. When I run this test I get the type error
TypeError: foodStore.getSnack.mockReturnValue is not a function

If I uncomment this line of the test
// foodStore.getSnack = jest.fn()

it passes. I don't mind it passing, but this has a bit of stink to me. Does pinia have a way of mocking actions or is it correct to re mock the action after the object is created?
import { setActivePinia, createPinia, getActivePinia } from 'pinia'
import { useMamaStore } from 'src/stores/mama'
import { useFoodStore } from 'src/stores/food'
export const getStore = (name) => {
  const store = getActivePinia()?._s.get(name)
  if (!store) throw new Error(`${name} store does not exist`)
  return store
}

jest.mock(
  'src/stores/food',
  () => {
    const { defineStore } = require('pinia')
    const useFoodStore = defineStore('food', {
      state: () => ({ snacks: 10 }),
      actions: {
        getSnack: jest.fn(),
      },
    })
    return { useFoodStore }
  },
)
describe('useMamaStore', () => {
  let mamaStore
  let foodStore

  beforeEach(() => {
    const pinia = createPinia()
    setActivePinia(pinia)
    foodStore = useFoodStore(pinia)
    // foodStore.getSnack = jest.fn()
    mamaStore = useMamaStore(pinia)

    jest.clearAllMocks() 
  })


  it('should make a snack if food store has snacks available', () => {
    // Mock food store to return a valid snack
    foodStore.getSnack.mockReturnValue(true)
    mamaStore.makeSnack()
    expect(foodStore.getSnack).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(mamaStore.snackMade).toBe(true) 
  })

})


● useMamaStore › should make a snack if food store has snacks available

TypeError: foodStore.getSnack.mockReturnValue is not a function

    58 |   it('should make a snack if food store has snacks available', () => {
    59 |     // Mock food store to return a valid snack
  > 60 |     foodStore.getSnack.mockReturnValue(true)
       |                        ^
    61 |     mamaStore.makeSnack()
    62 |     expect(foodStore.getSnack).toHaveBeenCalled()
    63 |     expect(mamaStore.snackMade).toBe(true) 

    at Object.mockReturnValue
      (test/jest/__tests__/stores/mama.jest.spec.js:60:24)


// src/stores/mama.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useFoodStore } from './food'

export const useMamaStore = defineStore('mama', {
  state: () => ({
    loving: true,
    caring: true,
    snackMade: false,
  }),
  getters: {
    timeForSnack(state) {
      return state.snackMade
    },
  },
  actions: {
    makeSnack() {
      const foodStore = useFoodStore()
      const snack = foodStore.getSnack()
      this.snackMade = snack
    },
  },
})

// src/stores/food.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useFoodStore = defineStore('food', {
  state: {
    delicious: true,
    snacks: 10,
  },
  getters,
  actions: {
    getSnack() {
      if (this.snacks === 0) {
        return false
      }
      this.snacks = this.snacks - 1
      return true
    },
  },
})


Even without checking how Pinia actions are implemented, it can be expected that foodStore.getSnack isn't the same function as provided in actions.getSnack option, but a wrapper around it, so foodStore.getSnack  isn't a Jest spy. An action is supposed to be bound to the context, so it could be destructured from store object, and calling an action is supposed to dispatch it, as seen in Pinia devtools.
But it can be expected that foodStore.getSnack calls actions.getSnack, so testing strategy is the same as for any mocked or spied function that is used locally in mocked module, the reference to a spy should be kept in order to access it in tests. That jest.mock is hoisted limits the way a spy can be made available in test module, this can be worked around by defining it as module export and importing it:
import { useFoodStore, getSnackMock } from 'src/stores/food'

jest.mock(
  'src/stores/food',
  () => {
    const getSnackMock = jest.fn();
    ...
      actions: { getSnack: getSnackMock }
    })
    return { useFoodStore, getSnackMock };
  },
)

...

getSnackMock.mockReturnValue(true)
mamaStore.makeSnack()
...

